# wayout to play audio in android app without Java code

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am planning to create a music app which allows user to choose from a number of inbuilt audio. The closest thing I found on the web was jPlayer plugin for jQuery which I couldn't make it work on Android. My app is based on jQuery mobile.

Is there any really simple way to add audio to my web app which I am planning to convert to .apk using phonegap. I intend to provide a list of links/file names to user in my app and on clicking the file name/link, the audio player controls shall be displayed and the selected audio shall start playing.

I have also tried the HTML embed tag and it also didn't work in the apk.

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap doesn't support the  tag yet as far as I know.

I have heard of people successfully using the PhoneGap API +jQuery Mobile to get it working via this tutorial: http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt1part1

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can use a PhoneGap plugin to do this:

```
window.plugins.webintent.startActivity({
    action: WebIntent.ACTION_VIEW,
    url: 'http"//whatever.mp4'}, 
    function() {console.log('Wow this actually worked!');}, 
    function() {console.log('Failed to open URL via Android Intent');}
);
```

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phonegap/nEm47r1Bhak